# More than one Controller - Beginners guide

Tags: symfony, controller

I just started with symfony 4 and have a question about "multi-controller", if my application got many routes, should i go for more controllers to keep the files tiny and readable or is one controller enough / recommended?

There is no recommended way about multi-controllers on the official documentation.

If multi-controller is a good choice, how to split?

If there a good documentation on the inet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes, you should have more than one controller. Symfony's best practices recommend to keep your controllers tiny and delegate much of your application logic to services that you create to handle different actions. For this, it is essential that you have a basic understanding of Dependency Injection, the Container pattern and, more specifically, how Symfony's DI Container works (how you can register services, for example).

There's tons of documentation on Symfony in the intenet. [This one](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html) on controllers.

KnpUniversity has some really good tutorials to get you started. Start with the Symfony series, then follow with Symfony Internals.

Also, you will greatly benefit from the features of the maker bundle, that will generate code for you really quickly. You can install it with `composer require maker`. Then, you can create a controller running `php bin/console make:controller`.